# Make onClick on <li> go to another view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i'm new on react and i'm doing a project, actually it's a to do list, and i need to make a router that when i click on my item on

they send me to details of this item. Here's my actual code. That's my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './List';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      items: []
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      term: '',
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: "center", margin: 5}}>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input style={{borderRadius: 3, borderColor: "black"}} 
          value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange} />
          <button style={{borderRadius: 3, borderColor: "black"}}>
            Adicionar</button>
        </form>
        <List items={this.state.items}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here my List.js

```
import React from 'react';

const List = ({ items }) => (

  <ul style={{display: "block", listStyleType: "none", backgroundColor: "red"}}>
    {
      items && items.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
  );

export default List;
```

So i now i will have to use some library to make the route, but first i need to know how i make my itens clickable and when i click they return something that can i redirect to a detail view. Make sense?

And there's a library that you guys recommend to do this job?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i think, you need to use custom links in react As:

1) `npm i react-router-dom`

2) `import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';`

3) And finally use `<Link to="paste_your_url_here" />`

you can also place `<Link to='' />` inside of ul, li.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `onClick` on each `li` that redirects to the url you want (implementation may vary based off the lib you choose to handle rooting), but that's not really a good idea since in HTML li are not supposed to be clickable.

What I would do is have a link (again, see with the routing lib - generally it provides a `<Link />` component) inside each `<li>`. This provides better semantic to your code.

Hope this makes sense.

As for a good library... React-router or reach-router are pretty nice!